# Two named PIPEs (PIPE_in/PIPE_out) connected with `tail -f` | String sent to PIPE_in doesn't reach PIPE_out

Tags: pipe, fifo, mkfifo

1.Create named PIPEs, `pipe_in` and `pipe_out` by running:

```
$ mkfifo pipe_in
$ mkfifo pipe_out
```

2.Connect `pipe_in` to `pipe_out`:

```
TERM0: $ tail -f pipe_in > pipe_out
```

3.Send string `hello world!` to `pipe_in` and expect it to arrive at `pipe_out`:

```
TERM1: $ tail -f pipe_out
TERM2: $ echo "hello world!" > pipe_in
```

I can only see the string arriving at `pipe_out` if I kill command in `2.`.
It seems to be a buffering issue so I decided to run all commands above with `stdbuf -i0 -e0 -o0 <command>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Good point, @Jeff Schaller. I have just deleted that question. I find this one, here, more fundamental. As soon as I solve this one I will likely be able to solve the other one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tail` only outputs the last n lines of a file/stream. **While you are still generating lines, it can not know which are the last n.**

Have you tried something like `cat`?

Comment: It is interesting though that the tail from one pipe to the other works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to @ctrl-alt-delor's answer for the reason why it doesn't work. But you can still achieve the same purpose with `cat`:

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting that it works on your setup. On my setup it doesn't. I am running this on OSX, btw - not sure if it should make any difference, though...
Altough, if I replace both `tail` commands by `cat` it all works fine.

Comment: exactly, that is also puzzling me...